# alternative of useEffect for react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, graphql

First, I run a graphql query and then use its results to render some items using the `FlatList`. This works fine.

On another screen, I run another mutation using apollos **refetch** option, such that whenever that mutation is successful, the first query will refetch data where ever it is used. The refetching part works fine and I have tested it on other screens. So automatically, the `data` in `WhiteList` is **updated**.

However the `friendList` is **not updated** so the **FlatList doesn't get updated**.

How can I fix this? `useEffect`could have been an option but using the custom graphql hook inside it gives me `invalid hook call` error. What else can I do?

```
export const WhitelistBar: React.FC = () => {
  const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Friend[]>();
  const [originatorId, setOriginatorId] = useState<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log('friendlist', friendList);
  }, [useGetMyProfileQuery]);
  
  const _onCompleted = (data) => {
    console.log('running', data);
    let DATA = data.me.friends.nodes.map(
      (item: {
        id: number;
        firstName: string;
        rating: number;
        vehicles: Vehicle[];
        friends: UserConnection;
      }) => ({
        id: item.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.firstName,
        rating: item.rating,
        vehicles: item.vehicles,
        numberOfFriends: item.friends.totalCount,      
      }),
    );
    setFriendList(DATA);
    console.log('daattaaa', DATA);
    setOriginatorId(data.me.id)
  };

  const _onError = () => {
    let DATA = [
      {
        id: 1,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
    ];
    setFriendList(DATA);
    setOriginatorId(0);
  };

  const { data } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    onCompleted: _onCompleted,
    onError: _onError,
  });

  return (
    <View style={scaledStyles.container}>
      <View style={scaledStyles.whiteListBarTitle}>
        <Text style={scaledStyles.whiteListBarText}>Meine Freunde</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <FlatList
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={friendList}
          horizontal={true}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <WhitelistItem
              title={item.name}
              face={item.imageUrl}
              numberOfFriends={item.numberOfFriends}
              vehicles={item.vehicles}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Edit:

I also tried this but this renders nothing for now:

```
 const showFlatList = (friendList: Friend[] | undefined) => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={friendList}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <WhitelistItem
            title={item.name}
            face={item.imageUrl}
            firstName={item.name}
            rating={item.rating}
            numberOfFriends={item.numberOfFriends}
            vehicles={item.vehicles}
            originatorId={originatorId}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      />
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    showFlatList(friendList);
  }, [useGetMyProfileQuery]);
```

and this in the main return instead of the FlatList:

```
 {data && showFlatList}
```

Also, tried this but `Argument of type '(DATA: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.ts(2345)`

```
     useEffect((DATA: any) => {
        setFriendList(DATA)
      }, [DATA])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hook as effect dependency - only variables/props/values.

You can use hook inside effect function (body).

If it is a component dependent on other (parent's) data/values - pass them as prop and use in effect dependency.

Comment: Do you mean that I should render the flatList inside the useEffect? I tried that but didn't work for me. Could you see the updated qs?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. The friendList depends on the ```DATA```so I should pass ```DATA``` as the prop and use it as a dependency? Tried that too